# Какие проекты написать для закрепления знаний на C#?

Tags: c#

Я заканчиваю читать Шилдта по C#. Хочу закрепить знания на практике. Писал уже калькулятор и телефонный справочник. Что еще можно попробовать написать?

Comment: Аналогичный случай по СИ. Я не знаю, что мне делать на нём. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, Вы серьезно ?  

Попробуйте сделать библиотеку для Си с функциями типа malloc(), free() ... для shared memory (лучше posix), чтобы из разных процессов можно было в таком блоке строить динамические структуры (например очереди и т.п.).

Основная проблема в том, что такой блок в разных процессах может отображаться на разные адреса.

Если получится - опубликуйте.

Answer (score 4):

Вот неплохие задачи: [архив](http://acm.timus.ru/problemset.aspx?space=1&page=all&sort=difficulty).

Comment: ну это закрепление алгоритмов скорее будет (причем далеко не самый простой архив)

Comment: Вот это задание больше всего прикольнуло:


http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1000

Comment: @Asen стандартное задание во всех архивах проверить систему

Answer (score 1):

[посмотри тут](http://cofounder.ru/) там и идею найдешь и команду заодно) все таки участие в opensource проектах дает хороший опыт... и при устройстве на работу поможет)

Answer (score 0):

Что-нибудь для работы с базой данных, например. Заодно и синтаксис Sql-запросов подучите :)

Comment: например? с базовым синтаксисом знаком) Предмет в универе учил, не спал) Курсовую сам делал пр sql)

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую делать работы из разряда курсовых проектов. Просто приходите к преподу в универе и говорите какие у вас есть темы по изучению такого то языка. Кстати можно в этом деле и подзаработать немного

Comment: в университете уже каникулы и преподы в отпусках)

Comment: это слова школьника я так понимаю? да будет вам известно, что у студентов сессии заканчиваются в конце июня и до того момента преподы из универа ни ногой.

Comment: с абсолютной точностью уверяю, что в Украине уже защитились дипломники, т.к. из-за небезизвестных событий учебный год сократили

Comment: alvin, вот что у людей за мода, с умничать не зная ситуацит? Я уже сдал сессию и закончил третий курс. Я живу в Украине. И за евро 2012 сократили учебный год.

Comment: ничего не знаю. Вы же говорите на русском. Данный сайт хостится в России. 78% посетителей также русские. Надо было уточнять в первом комменте что вы украинец. И ещё если вы сдали сессию, то это не значит что и преподы тоже свободны. У них остаётся куча всякой рутины и помимо вас. Да и 3 месяца отпуск это слишком жииирно

Comment: по вашему, украинец обязан говорить на украинском? Побывайте на Украине и вам все станет понятно) Почему, я должен был это уточнять, это не как не касается данной темы.

Comment: @ArniLand ещё раз повторяю - у меня не было никакого повода предполагать что вы находитесь на Украине. И мой совет направлен на помощь большинству и не учитывает таких деталей

Answer (score 0):

Не буду повторяться, что уже перечислено. Но я когда изучал, то заходил на фриланс-биржы, и смотрел какие проекты есть. И пытался для себя их сделать. Так можно оценить свои знания на более-менее реальных проектах, и сколько времени потратил.

Comment: Ну, на фриланс биржах проекты совсем не для закрепления (сложноваты для такого занятия)